How can I write a Chrome and Firefox Manifest v3 extension that shares code when their manifests are mutually incompatible?
I'm currently working on a browser extension for both Chrome and Firefox that shares much of the same code.
However, the extension requires a background script, and starting with manifest v3, Chrome and Firefox now handle these in a mutually incompatible way. In manifest.json's background entry, Chrome requires the use of service_worker while Firefox still requires using scripts. Consequently, I can't create a manifest that works with both apps.
Is there a convenient way I can get both browsers to load an unpacked extension, where each uses a different manifest, but while still loading the same code?
The only idea I can think of is to create two folders for both browsers, each with a separate manifest, and then symlinking to the scripts themselves. But that strikes me as being problematic for a number of reasons, one being the need to maintain the symlinks when files move or change, and the other is for Windows users who would try to check out the extension's git repository given Windows' poor support for symlinks. I'm hoping there's a better method.
edit: And symlinks don't work anyway! Neither Chrome nor Firefox will load content scripts that are symlinks.

Usually it's solved by using a bundler like webpack, but in new Chrome you can specify both scripts and service_worker, the former will be ignored with a warning in unpacked mode, so if you don't need to support the old Chrome you're fine.

@wOxxOm That's a good idea, though now the project has evolved to the point that Firefox is using Manifest v2 and Chrome is using v3, so I really do need two separate manifest files!

This is still something that's usually solved by webpack/rollup/etc. The source is compiled according to the chosen recipe (mv2/mv3) into the output directory.

Hi @BriBri, did you managed to make it work, i am stuck in a same problem. The only difference is in a manifest.json file in that case i may need to create two seprate folder with different manifest.json files.

@NomanZahid I ended up doing a total hack, and using hard links. I wrote a script that would generate a "firefox" folder with its manifest.json file, and then hard links to all of the other source files. That would load in Firefox. Totally not the best way to do it, and probably unworkable in Windows -- I'm not even sure what kind of hard link support it has -- but it worked as a stopgap.
